# How to replace content of a span class via Javascript in an angular environment?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, replace

My goal is to replace the content of a html span class using javascript. Easy task, since you can just use *element.getElementsByTagName("span")*, right?

But I have an app that was written in angular and the actual span classes are not displayed inside the source code that my browser is showing me (view-source:https://samplesite.com/item).
This is what the *view-source feature* displays me what is inside the body tag:

```
<body>
  <ds-app></ds-app>
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles.js" defer></script><script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script></body>
```

And this is what the *development console (F12)* displays me what is actually inside the body tag:

```
[...]
<ds-generic-item-page-field _ngcontent-dspace-angular-c521="" ng-reflect-item="[object Object]" ng-reflect-fields="dc.rights.cc" ng-reflect-label="item.page.rights-cc"><div class="item-page-field"><ds-metadata-values _nghost-dspace-angular-c228="" ng-reflect-md-values="[object Object]" ng-reflect-separator="<br/>" ng-reflect-label="item.page.rights-cc"><ds-metadata-field-wrapper _ngcontent-dspace-angular-c228="" _nghost-dspace-angular-c227="" ng-reflect-label="Creative Commons Lizenz"><div _ngcontent-dspace-angular-c227="" class="simple-view-element"><h5 _ngcontent-dspace-angular-c227="" class="simple-view-element-header ng-star-inserted">Creative Commons Lizenz</h5><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "Creative Commons Lizenz"
}--><div _ngcontent-dspace-angular-c227="" class="simple-view-element-body"><span _ngcontent-dspace-angular-c228="" class="dont-break-out ng-star-inserted"> CC-BY-NC<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
}--></div></div></ds-metadata-field-wrapper></ds-metadata-values></div></ds-generic-item-page-field>
[...]
```

I guess that this is why my *getElementsByTagName* cannot find the span classes - they seem to not be accessible because they seem to be rendered differently. My question is: How is it possible to get the contents of all span classes using javascript in this scenario? Am I missing something important here? Why is the code shown in view-source so different compaired to the development console?

My Goal is to replace "CC-BY-NC" in my example with a Link to a Website. Pretty simple but its driving me crazy. Any help that points me in the right direction would be much appreceated. :)

P.S.: I have no experience with angular, so sorry if I am asking an completely obvious question.

So far nothing seems to bring me closer to my goal since I cannot adress these span classes using javascript. I have put my JS-code inside an Typescript file and it seems to be executed but as stated above, cannot find any span classes.

Comment: Have you tried `document.querySelector('.dont-breakout')`?

Comment: There are some unclear points in your question. First of all, the link you posted doesn't show anything (at least to me). Also, you're talking about "span classes" but you're trying to retrieve span elements by tag name not class. As a general rule, direct DOM manipulation using JS should be avoided in Angular. I guess you're issue can be solved simply by using a binding but you should tell us more about this use case. When exaclty should the content be replaced? Depending on which condition?

Comment: Thanks Ibsn for your answer! And sorry for my unclear post, I am new to web development and still a bit struggling with all the concepts. First, the link above is just there to illustrate what I mean with "Source-Code in Browser" and is not meant to be an acutal link. My use case: I want to replace the content of an span element containg "CC-BY-NC" with a Link to the Creative Commons Website. Thats all.

Comment: @tony7654 Sorry, still not very clear. Anyway you can certainly retrieve a HTML element using `document.getElementsByTagName()`, as long as the component has been mounted and the element injected into the DOM. And of course you can manipulate that element. Take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uekryq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). But as I said, this is not the best way to accomplish this sort of things in Angular.